# Matching string contains x and followed by y

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I want to evaluate to true if a string contains the word ‘except’ AND is followed by ‘xyz’. For example

```
blah except xyz => true
except xyz => true
blah except abc => false
blah except abc, xyz => true
blah except xyz, abc => true
xyz except abc => false
```

What is the most pythonic way of doing this? Regular expressions seem over kill. This would probably only be used in one function. I've used the `in` operator to find the `except` part of the string, but I'm not sure how to proceed. This should not be case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

`"except(?=[^\n]*?xyz)"`

- It will take the text `except`only
- if until the line's end `[^\n]*?`
- it is possible to find `xyz`.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/tW7nK0/3)

---

How to use it in python?

```
import re
word = 'blah except xyz => true'
regexp = re.compile(r'except(?=[^\n]*?xyz)')
if regexp.search(word) is not None:
  print 'matched'
```

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you put it into Python though? I tried `if re.match(r'except?=.*?xyz', row[0]):` and it doesn't match.

Comment: `match()` only succeeds if the pattern is found at the _beginning_ of the string. `search()` succeeds if the pattern is found _anywhere_ in the string.

Comment: By the way, `.` matches every character except for newline by default, so you can replace `[^\n]` with `.`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3. Yeah, I did that in version 1 of regex101, but to illustrate the input with multiline I've changed... Anyways, it won't fail

Answer (score 3):

How about with string operations?

```
if 'except' in my_string.lower() and my_string.lower().find('xyz') > my_string.lower().find('except'):
    return True
```

You could also use EAFP and avoid looking for `'except'` twice:

```
try:
    if my_string.lower().index('xyz') > my_string.lower().index('except'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
except ValueError:
    return False
```

It's simpler if you only need truthy/falsey values rather than actual booleans:

```
try:
    if my_string.lower().index('xyz') > my_string.lower().index('except'):
        return True
except ValueError:
    return
```

Comment: "truthy/falsey values rather than actual booleans" what's the difference?

Comment: Certain things like empty iterables (`set`, `list`, `str`, etc.), `None`, and `0`, when used as a predicate, evaluate to `False`. However, they are not actually equal to the boolean value. So, if a failure returns `None` instead of `False`, `if check(my_string):` would work fine, but `sum(check(my_string) for my_string in strings)` would not.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where regex does make sense:

```
if re.search('except.*xyz', string):
    ...
```

Simple, fast and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is most readable:

```
'except' in my_string and 'xyz' in my_string.split('except', 1)[1]
```