# Python Skip Consecutive Separator In Split

Tags: python, regex, split

I need to split a string by "\" separator. But i have to skip the consecutive occurrences.
More precisely, for my goal "//sensor1" needs to be read like '/sensor1'.

```
import re
a = "root/master/sensors//sensor1/value"
re.split("/+", a)
```

So i need to obtain:

```
['root', 'master', 'sensors//sensor1', 'value']
```

I tried that code, but maybe i did an error in the regex expression.

Comment: What if the input is `a = "root/master/sensors///sensor1/value"`

Comment: Thanks @WashingtonGuedes, i need an output like this https://regex101.com/r/vT6kH0/2
How can i do this in python?

Comment: @lovemint. In this answer: _http://stackoverflow.com/a/31928639/4227915_ I had provided an example in python. With slight changes you will got it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x="root/master/sensors//sensor1/value"
print re.split(r"(?<!\/)\/",x)
```

You can use `lookbehind` here to make sure only one `/` splits.

Output:`['root', 'master', 'sensors', '/sensor1', 'value']`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [*positive look behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split the text based on the forward slashes that precede by a word character :

```
>>> re.split(r"(?<=\w)/", a)
['root', 'master', 'sensors', '/sensor1', 'value']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) before the `/` and it will require a word letter to be to the left of `/` (note it does not have to be escaped in Python):

```
import re
a = "root/master/sensors//sensor1/value"
print(re.split(r"\b/", a))
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/YC012h)

Output:

```
['root', 'master', 'sensors', '/sensor1', 'value']
```